# Missing std::front and std::back

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a reason `std::front` and `std::back` are not present in C++11?
There is `std::begin` and `std::end` so to me, having the *equivalent* with regards to actual instances would make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` are supposed to work for *all* fundamental containers (including C-style arrays).

In fact, if the container supports member `begin()` and `end()` functions, `std::begin()` and `std::end()` forward the call to those member functions.

However, not all containers support `front()` and `back()` member functions.

Comment: Just to clarify, all containers really mean all containers, even plain arrays.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Sure. But I will emphasize this, thank you.

Comment: Though, `std::stack` does not support `begin` and `end`.

Comment: @LCIDFire: True. That's a container *adapter* though, not a fundamental container.

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes, but IMO as long as a container has a _bidirectional iterator_ having even a `std::back` should not be a problem.

Comment: @LCIDFire: Not all fundamental containers have a bidirectional iterator though (see `forward_list`).

Comment: @AndyProwl Ok, having only a _forward iterator_ is a showstopper there.

Comment: A proper answer should explain, that begin()/end() and front()/back() is related to container behavior. There are more cases like push_back() which are not present in all containers.

Comment: @CodeClown: I honestly don't think this answer is worth downvoting just because it misses one ambiguous sentence of yours, but it's your right to think otherwise.

Comment: I would love to have this as well. In fact I am not sure why front and back are not present in std::map etc. Front and back may throw if container is empty. The free from could then operate like how the free from begin and end are implemented.

Comment: Made a feature request for Boost out of it: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11497